# jQuery cycle: fading white text becomes "green" in Windows/Firefox/Cleartype Enabled

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, jquery-cycle, cleartype

On Windows it seems that when there's white text on any background and it does transitions, the text naturally turns to some shade of green during its `opacity` value being toggled back to 1.

This makes sense. But does anyone know any sort of workaround to prevent it transitioning to a shade of green between the animating besides changing the color of the text from white to something else?

I have a full demo [here](http://medero.org/cycle.html).

Notes:

- It doesn't do it for me in Linux since there is no ClearType, it only happens when I enable ClearType on Windows.
- I specified `cleartype:true cleartypeNoBg` but as far as I know, that only resolves another issue in IE7.
- I know that if you disable ClearType it will go away

I would be open to maybe some sort of workaround that involves a different animation style ( other than fading ), but throw any ideas you have at me.

**EDIT**: Think I have found the bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363861).

**EDIT #2**: Looking through the transitions [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html). Seems like scrollRight may substitute for a fade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify a background color on the text element and you'll no longer see any green

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I think I resorted to another fading function and evaded this, but this works. I have updated the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this too when I have a fade transition, the fade seems to add luminous green when the text is grey. Looks kind of awful but appears fine in ie family!!

Have switched of the fade for now.

!